# Javascript function cannot be found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in document.ready()

```
if ($("#site-master").length > 0) {

    setMinContentHeight();

    function setMinContentHeight() {

        // removed for clarity
    }
}
```

I simply check if the page is correct (#site-master), then call my minimum height function, however I'm getting the following error in firebug: ReferenceError: setMinContentHeight is not defined.

I'm no javascript expert, but how can this be? The function works if I move it outside of document.ready(). I have checked and the code inside the if statement is reached.

Also, is this the best way of achieving what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your function above the call

Comment: you should define that function before you use it

Comment: That's an invalid location for a function declaration.

Comment: Your function is called before it is declared, which would not happen if you moved it to the global scope (ie outside document.ready())

Comment: it's valid...... myalert(); function myalert(){ alert('asd'); }

Comment: It's invalid to have function declaration in blocks which are not function declaration blocs. Different browsers handle that case differently.

Comment: @dystroy - is it better to put the function outside of document.ready() or not?

Comment: @dotnetnoob as you want. Inside is fine. Just don't put it in the `if` block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Never** declare your functions inside `if` or `for` statements:

```
function setMinContentHeight() {
    // removed for clarity
}

if ($("#site-master").length > 0) {
    setMinContentHeight();
}
```

If we address the [**ECMAScript specification**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), according to [**Chapter 12**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12), `if` clause is considered to be a *Statement* (as well as `for`, `while`, `with`, `try/catch`, etc).

Hence, following the *NOTE* from *Semantics* section:

> Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support
>   the use of `FunctionDeclaration` as a `Statement`. However there are
>   significant and irreconcilable variations among the implementations in
>   the semantics applied to such *FunctionDeclarations*. Because of these
>   irreconcilable differences, the use of a `FunctionDeclaration` as a
>   `Statement` results in code that is not reliably portable among
>   implementations. It is recommended that ECMAScript implementations
>   either disallow this usage of `FunctionDeclaration` or issue a warning
>   when such a usage is encountered. Future editions of ECMAScript may
>   define alternative portable means for declaring functions in a
>   `Statement` context.

It means that we cannot guarantee the consistent behavior in such cases, and, as a result, we will always get exception in `strict mode` in case if function was declared inside the *statement*.

Comment: @dystroy Is it the best of the worst? :)

Comment: No, it's right. You could precise that browsers handle function declared in conditioned blocks in different ways. And an ecmascript reference would probably bring more rep.

Comment: @dystroy: It's not explicitly mentioned in the spec. You can just point to the production of [`SourceElement`](http://es5.github.com/#x14)

Comment: @Bergi Well, there is some sort of note in Chapter 12. I have added the note to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the notes about *FunctionDeclaration* vs *Statement* and the incompatible syntax extensions in various browsers.  It is a useful lesson!

Answer (score 4):

First, read on [the difference between `var functionName = function() {}` and `function functionName() {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?rq=1) to understand function declarations vs expressions. Now what do you have? Nothing of the two, since function declarations need to be on the top level of function/script code - nesting them in blocks is [not allowed](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks). It's called a [*function statement*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-statements), is nonstandard and working differently.

Put it outside the `if`-block:

```
// here
if ($("#site-master").length > 0) {
    setMinContentHeight();
}
// or here:
function setMinContentHeight() {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("#site-master").length > 0) {
    setMinContentHeight();
}
function setMinContentHeight() {
        // removed for clarity
}
```

You need to declare your function in the global scope.

Comment: No, not the global scope : just at the root level of the scope, which might be a function.

Answer (score 2):

Place the call **after** you've defined the function and don't define functions inside an if block:

```
function setMinContentHeight() {
    // removed for clarity
}

if ($("#site-master").length > 0) {
    setMinContentHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problems with browser compatibility, but it works like this:

right:

```
n();
function n(){ alert('1'); }
```

wrong:

```
n();
var n = function(){ alert('1'); }
```

Comment: No : that's only valid at the root level of the scope, not in an inner conditionned scope.

Comment: @dystroy this works too: 

    if(true){
        n();
        function n(){alert('1');}
    }

Comment: Please read the links Bergi provides : http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks

Comment: @dystroy thanks, I have learned something new. But in question code everything should work