# Only execute a function if body class exists

Tags: javascript

I have a body class like this:

```
<body class="horizontal">
```

I try to target with the following code:

```
'use strict';

// Horizontal scrolling
// http://www.dte.web.id/2013/02/event-mouse-wheel.html
(function() {
if(document.body.className === 'horizontal') {
  alert('It exists');

  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    // Scroll to the left or right in `document.documentElement` and `document.body`
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta * 75); // Multiplied by 75
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta * 75); // Multiplied by 75
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollHorizontally, false); // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrollHorizontally, false); // Firefox
  } else {
    window.attachEvent('onmousewheel', scrollHorizontally); // IE 6/7/8
  }
};
})();
```

But this is just not working. The `alert` not popping up. I would like to prefer a pure javascript solution, to not include Jquery because of this.

EDIT: I uncommented the horizontal scroller function, then it's working. So the script is causing the issue.

The entire script is called at the bottom of the body.

Comment: Did the DOM even load before that function is executed?

Comment: Is this JavaScript code before or inside of the `<body>` tag? You'll need to show a complete web page with HTML and `<script>` tags.

Comment: [How to use the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: your code is working check this >> https://jsfiddle.net/vp6htpf8/   as others said you have to put {<script>} after the body is loaded

Comment: You would be better off using `document.body.classList.contains('horizontal')`.

Comment: @VivekSolanki Yes, with the “load type” set to “onload”, it obviously works.

Comment: No need for `attachEvent`--that's some historical artifact.

Comment: The `scrollHorizontally` function is irrelevant if you want the alert to popup. Check your console for errors because there's something else going on if it isn't failing when you include that script.

Comment: No it's not, because I uncommented it than the script is executing the alert, but if `scrollHorizontally` present, then even `alert` not executing.

Comment: @torazaburo - IIFE no?

Comment: duplicate of [Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or immediately within another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573061/uncaught-syntaxerror-in-strict-mode-code-functions-can-only-be-declared-at-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`just remove "'use strict';"` and it will work [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/vp6htpf8/1/)

Comment: It works! Thank You! Can you give me an explanation why causing this?

Comment: No, with use strict it only runs if I uncommenting `scrollHorizontally` (which why I got lots of downvoting, because the "smart ones" thought presenting in the code that part was irrelevant to the question). I use Firefox latest. https://jsfiddle.net/vp6htpf8/3/

Comment: @apsillers Firefox 44.0.2 x64 Running this there's NO ANY ALERT, just only if I uncommenting the `scrollHorizontally`: https://jsfiddle.net/vp6htpf8/2/

Comment: @apsillers yeah same for me , browser is causing the problem

Comment: Than I officialy want rehabilitation with upvotes. :D

Comment: @Lanti You've already been told to look in the browser's error console (press ctrl-shift-K). The error message would have told you immediately what the problem is ("in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function").

Comment: I checked in Chrome finally, it works and there's no console errors. Firefox giving the console error that you described.