# What does "Functions can only be declared at the top level of a scope" mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Strict mode introduces some kinds of breaking changes. one of them is :

> Functions can only be declared at the top level of a scope.

I am not able to understand this. Can anyone please describe it with an example?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573061/uncaught-syntaxerror-in-strict-mode-code-functions-can-only-be-declared-at-top

Comment: Review Mozilla developer network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/